# useLazyQuery - Re-Rendering Issue

Tags: javascript, react-native, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

Requirement:

I want to call the query the 1st time automatically in useEffect and then manually in the functions.

> Issue: Invarient Violation: Too many re-renders.

```
 const [getComment, { loading, data }] = useLazyQuery(getCommentsQuery);
  useEffect(() => {
    getComment({
      variables: {
        input: {
          id: "5e5cb512e90bd40017385305",
        },
      },
    });
  }, []);

  if (data && data.getPost) {
    var allNewComments = data.getPost.comments;
    setAllComments(allNewComments);  // re-renders
  }
```

`setState` is causing this issue, I'm assuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Body parts' of functional component are run for every change, needs conditions (or `useEffect` hooks) to block unexpected behaviours.

Just don't use `useState` for `allComments`? You can use f.e.

```
const allNewComments = (data && data.getPost) ? data.getPost.comments : [];
```

... if you want to iterate over `allNewComments`

If you still want to use `useState` (in combination with `useLazyQuery`) ... use it in `onCompleted` option/handler, sth like:

```
const [getComment, { loading, data }] = useLazyQuery(getCommentsQuery, {
  variables: {
    input: {
      id: "5e5cb512e90bd40017385305",
    },
  },
  onCompleted: (data) => {setAllNewComments( data.getPost.comments )}
```